# How to merge the same method of different classes that use private members

Tags: c++, oop, qt, class-design

I've just registered here, so before anything, thanks for reading!

I'm developing an application using Qt, but I need some advices regarding sharing class members.
I am working with some collections (QHash) of project-specific structs and I created a polymorphic class to manage those collections. A derived class also manage some UI components (shared through pointers or references) so it can automatically represent those structs in the UI.. It's something like this:

Main class

```
class ArmyEditor : public QMainWindow
{
//.... some specific functions ...

private:
    Ui::ArmyEditor *ui;

    // Specific structs
    QHash<QString, GameCategory> categories;
    QHash<QString, Column> columns;
    QHash<QString, GameProperty> properties;
    QHash<QString, UnitOption> commonOptions;
    QHash<QString, UnitOption> inheritedOptions;
    QHash<QString, GameItem> items;
    QHash<QString, GameItem> inheritedItems;
    QHash<QString, GlobalText> globalTexts;
    QHash<QString, GlobalText> inheritedGlobalTexts;
    QHash<QString, Unit> units;
};
```

Base class for collection managing..

```
class StructManager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit StructManager(QWidget* parent = 0);

    // ...Functions that perform actions in shared components...

protected:
    QWidget *parent;
    QHash<QString, GameCategory> *categories;
    QHash<QString, Column> *columns;
    QHash<QString, GameProperty> *properties;
    QHash<QString, UnitOption> *commonOptions;
    QHash<QString, GameItem> *commonItems;
    QHash<QString, GlobalText> *globalTexts;
    QHash<QString, Unit> *units;
};
```

Derived class for UI management and so on

```
class StructEditor : public StructManager
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    StructEditor(QWidget* parent = 0);

    // ...Overriden functions to automatically represent structs in the shared members..

protected:
    QTreeWidget *catList;
    QListWidget *colList;
    QTreeWidget *propList;
    QTreeWidget *optList;
    QListWidget *optActionList;
    QTreeWidget *itemList;
    QListWidget *itemActionList;
    QTableWidget *globalTextsGrid;
    QTreeWidget *unitTree;
    QComboBox *optCategory;
    QComboBox *itemCategory;
    QComboBox *unitCategory;
    QComboBox *optAmountColumn;
    QComboBox *optSetColumn;
};
```

And I share some UI members in the constructor of the MainWindow class..

```
ArmyEditor::ArmyEditor(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ArmyEditor)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Setup Army Struct Manager

    armyManager = new StructEditor(this);

    armyManager->setCatList(ui->catList);
    armyManager->setOptList(ui->optList);
    armyManager->setOptActionList(ui->optActionList);
    armyManager->setItemList(ui->itemList);
    armyManager->setItemActionList(ui->itemActionList);
    armyManager->setGlobalTextsGrid(ui->globalTextsGrid);
    armyManager->setUnitTree(ui->unitTree);
    armyManager->setOptCategory(ui->optCategory);
    armyManager->setItemCategory(ui->itemCategory);
    armyManager->setUnitCategory(ui->unitCategory);
    armyManager->setOptAmountColumn(ui->optAmountColumn);
    armyManager->setOptSetColumn(ui->optSetColumn);
    armyManager->setCategories(&categories);
    armyManager->setOptions(&commonOptions);
    armyManager->setItems(&items);
    armyManager->setGlobalTexts(&globalTexts);

    //.. some other code ..
};
```

I call the functions from the StructEditor class when I need to add a new Category or something like that..
My project consists of three applications, those of which use almost the same methods for managing these structs, so I decided to use a class with the methods to add, update, remove and represent the structs in the UI sharing some member pointers with the MainWindow class. But now I'm thinking it is a bit dirty and I should not share these members because the MainWindow loses control over them. I was thinking I could create the collections of my structs in the Base class and make a method so I can read (securely) members of those collections in the MainWindow class, but my problem is with UI members. I could use signals and manage those members directly in the MainWindow class, but then I would have to duplicate a lot of code and it would complicate (a bit) the code changes, which is the main reason I decided to unify those methods in a class.

So, my question is: Is there any way to 'unify' those methods without having to share members or using global variables (because would have the same effect)? I would like to have those methods in a separated file.

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: If you have similar logic used by multiple applications that can share a common interface that sounds like the perfect time to make a library project (dll or lib) that the applications can all use via some sort of API.

Comment: @AJG85 Thanks for your answer! Maybe it is a good idea, but I run into the same problem: modifying the UI members without sharing them. I think "the cleaner" solution would be doing this in the MainWindow class (the one that controls the UI), but I don't want to repeat the same code..

Thanks!

Comment: A model/view architecture works well in Qt. In general it's easier to make changes if your gui is not coupled to your data.

Comment: In my code the data is managed apart from the UI. It's something like Model/View, but anyway it does not solve my problem of redundant code.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I was thinking I could pass a reference of the UI widget each time I need to modify it rather than storing a pointer. How good is this considering the method I'm using right now? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the inheritance you have provided and where your data resides.

As AJG85 pointed out you should decouple your data from your manipulators and view so for example:

```
class StructManager {
private:
    typedef QHash<QString, GameCategory> CategoryT;
    CategoryT categories;
    ....
public:
    CategoryT& getCategories() { return categories; }
};

class StructEditor : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
protected:
    StructManager sm;
...
};

class ArmyEditor : public StructEditor
{
public:
    <manipulation methods>
};

class ArmyWindow : public MainWindow
{
private:
    ArmyEditor ae;
....
};
```

Once you have followed this structure you will find that all events from the UI can be passed on to your editors which manipulate data and display fields that read it.

This way your have no sharing of data between object and no code duplication.  If you want to be really fancy do this:

```
class BaseEditor
{
protected:
    void ManipulateCategories() = 0;
};

class StructEditor : public QObject, public BaseEditor
{
   ....
};

class ArmyEditor : public QObject, public BaseEditor
{
 ....
};
```

I am sure you can figure out implementations for the individual editor classes.

Comment: Just would like to say that after many time, I have got experience with UI decoupling and some design patterns like MVC and now really understand what all of you really meant. Fortunately, my code was not SO coupled as there were some 'layers' between real data and UI, so it is easy to fix the mistake. Thank you so much and excuse me for marking this as answer so late